# Are USB Wi-Fi adapters compatible with Kali in WSL2

Tags: kali-linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Will WSL automatically recognize a USB Wi-Fi adapter and will I be able to use it. If not how can I direct it to WSL?

I want to use an external USB wifi adapter because you can't use the same adapter as the host for wireless auditing in Kali using programmes like Wifite.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to use a USB Wi-Fi adapter but you will have some setup to do.

1. Open **Hyper-V Manager** as *Administrator*.
2. Go to **Virtual Switch Manager**.
3. Select **WSL**.
4. Change the connection type to **External network**.
5. Choose your Wi-Fi adapter.
6. If you want, untick the box that says *Allow management operating system to share this network adapter*.
7. Press **OK** to save the changes and exit **Hyper-V Manager**.
8. Open **WSL**.
9. Then run these 2 commands.

> ```
> sudo ip addr flush dev eth0 
> sudo dhclient eth0
> ```

10. Check if the internet connection is working by pinging google.com
11. If it doesn't try reopening WSL.
12. If it still doesn't work, change the nameserver in `/etc/resolve.conf` to a different DNS like Google (8.8.8.8) or Cloudflare (1.1.1.1)

Source - [Can we connect USB WiFi adapter to WSL2 for WiFi Hacking? || Networking in WSL2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NOOUfsExYCE)

Comment: Any idea how to safely revert it back?

Answer (score 2):

Okay so, I edited the kernel itself to allow you to actually be able to use WiFi adapters as well as loadable modules, etc in WSL2

If anyone's interested here you go
https://github.com/EDLLT/WSL2-Linux-Kernel

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/411850)